# Error in load group of png images into colab using imagefolder

Tags: image, pytorch, load, display, google-colaboratory

I am writing a code to load a group of images (50 images) from my google drive into colab system , then display them. i upload all image on drive and mount them correctly but i still have a problem
here is my code: [image]

Comment: even the colab read all the 50 image and mounted them , but it say that no data

Comment: Are you sure the folder is not zipped or similar?